# How can I store numbers > 128 in a signed one byte interger?

Tags: assembly, binary, numbers, twos-complement, signed-integer

I am reading the book *Art of Assembly Language*. There I came across this paragraph.

> If the H.O. bit is zero, then the number is positive and is stored as a
>    standard binary value. If the H.O. bit is one, then the number is
>    negative and is stored in the two’s comple-ment form. To convert a
>    positive number to its negative, two’s complement form, you use the
>    following algorithm:
>
> 1. Invert all the bits in the number, i.e., apply the logical `NOT` function.
> 2. Add one to the inverted result.
>
>    For example, to compute the eight bit equivalent of `-5`:
>
>    ```
>    0000 0101  Five (in binary)   
>    1111 1010  Invert all the bits.   
>    1111 1011  Add one to obtain result.
>    ```

Here I want to know if `0000 0101` is 5 in decimals and 1111 1011 is -5 then how we represent `251`? Is not the same `1111 1011`? How the computer distinguishes between -5 and `251`?

Comment: It's just a matter of interpreting. That's why there exist the instructions for signed and for unsigned values, because they treat the input differently. For example, the value `01` will mean `1` if interpreted as signed or unsigned. However, the value `11` would be interpreted as 3 if it's considered unsigned, or as -1 if we consider it signed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are representing signed numbers in 8 bits, the 8th bit (the HO bit) is the sign bit.  Therefore you can only use 7 bits to store the value of the number.  The range for a signed number in 8 bits is -128..127.  251 can't be represented, unless you use more than 8 bits.

Comment: by the way, that is a great book :)p

Comment: Oh, this was so easy. Did not come across my mind. Thanks a lot for quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

The computer doesn't distinguish between the two -- it's up to you to use the appropriate instructions.

For example, on the x86, you use `JA` (jump if Above) and `JB` (jump if below) for unsigned numbers and `JG` (jump if greater) and `JL` (jump if less than) for signed numbers. Likewise you use `IMUL` and `IDIV` to multiply/divide signed numbers and `MUL` and `DIV` for unsigned numbers.